# Visual Studio 2017 Community installation on TFS vanishes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I have installed TFS 2018 Update 2 on a Windows Server 2016 that joined my domain. In order to get the build system working I have also installed VS 2017 Community on the TFS.

After installing VS all seems to be fine. The Build Agent does its work.
But after a day or so, including a server restart, the Build Agent stops working complaining that VS is not installed.

Checking that turns out that all the files are present in their designated directory and also IDE starts, but also the VS installer only shows the install button. Trying to modify or uninstall VS via Control Panel fails with a message, that the product is not installed.

This behaviour is reproduceable as I, for now, have installed VS more than 4 times also on a new TFS setup using different accounts (Domain Admin, Local Admin).

Have someone encountered the same behaviour or can someone suggest a resolution?

Thanks and reagrds,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I have re-setup TFS machine and installed Visual Studio first even before adding to the domain with the latest vs web-installer. Now it seems to work.